# SCNShape doesn't draw a shape for NSBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, macos, scenekit

I experienced that for some `NSBezierPath`s  `SCNShape` seems to be unable to draw a shape.

The path is created only using `line(to:)`.

```
//...set up scene...

//Create path (working)
let path = NSBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
path.line(to: NSMakePoint(0.000000, 0.000000))
path.line(to: NSMakePoint(0.011681, 0.029526))
// more points ...
path.close()

// Make a 3D shape (not working)
let shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 10)
shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.green
let node = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
root.addChildNode(node)
```

For verifying that the general process of creating a `SCNShape` is correct, I also drew a blue shape that only differs by having different points. The blue shape gets drawn, the green shape doesn't.

You can find a playground containing the full example [here](https://gigamove.rz.rwth-aachen.de/d/id/AYUBLdsyCaPbw4). In the example you should be able to see a green and a blue shape in assistant editor. But only the blue shape gets drawn.

Do you have any idea why the green shape is not shown?

Comment: How good would it be if it was possible to copy and paste a shape from Illustrator or other vector program, into SceneKit's Scene Editor? Then scale it... etc. Or import an SVG, or other individual vector shape of some sort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short story: your path has way more points than it needs to, leading you to unexpected, hard to find geometric problems.

Note this bit in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnshape/1523432-init):

> The result of extruding a self-intersecting path is undefined.

As it turns out, somewhere in the first 8 or so points, your "curve" makes enough of a turn the wrong way that the line closing the path (between the first point in the path `0,0`, and the last point `32.366829, 29.713470`) intersects the rest of the path. Here's an attempt at making it visible by excluding all but the first few points and the last point from a playground render (see that tiny little zigzag in the bottom left corner):

[image: move zig for great justice]

And at least on some SceneKit versions/renderers, when it tries to make a mesh out of a self-intersecting path it just gives up and makes nothing.

However, you really don't need that many points to make your path look good. Here it is if you use 1x, 1/5x, and 1/10x as many points:

[image: original path]
[image: path w/ every 5th point from the original]
[image: path w/ every 10th point from the original]

If you exclude enough points overall, and/or skip the few at the beginning that make your curve zag where it should zig, SceneKit renders the shape just fine:

[image: first few points excluded, 1/5 as many points total]

---

Some tips from diagnosing the problem:

When working with lots of coordinate data like this, I like to use `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` so I can easily build an array of lots of points/vectors/etc:

```
extension CGPoint: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    public init(arrayLiteral elements: CGFloat...) {
        precondition(elements.count == 2)
        self.init(x: elements.first!, y: elements.last!)
    }
}

var points: [CGPoint] = [
    [0.000000, 0.000000],
    [0.011681, 0.029526],
    // ...
]
```

That gets me an array (and a lot less typing out things like `NSPointMake` over and over), so I can slice and dice the data to figure out what's wrong with it. (For example, one of my early theories was that there might be something about negative coordinates, so I did some `map` and `min()` to find the most-negative X and Y values, then some more `map` to make an array where all points are offset by a constant amount.)

Now, to make paths using arrays of points, I make an extension on `NSBezierPath`:

```
extension NSBezierPath {
    convenience init(linesBetween points: [CGPoint], stride: Int = 1)  {
        precondition(points.count > 1)
        self.init()
        move(to: points.first! )
        for i in Swift.stride(from: 1, to: points.count, by: stride) {
            line(to: points[i])
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I can easily create paths from not just entire arrays of points, but also...

- paths that skip parts of the original array (with the `stride` parameter)

  ```
  let path5 = NSBezierPath(linesBetween: points, stride: 5)
  let path10 = NSBezierPath(linesBetween: points, stride: 10)
  ```

  (This is handy for generating playground previews a bit more quickly, too.)
- paths that use some chunk or slice of the original array

  ```
  let zigzag = NSBezierPath(linesBetween: Array(points.prefix(to:10)) + [points.last!])
  let lopOffBothEnds = NSBezierPath(linesBetween: Array(points[1 ..< points.count < 1]))
  ```

Or both... the winning entry (in the screenshot above) is:

```
let path = NSBezierPath(linesBetween: Array(points.suffix(from: 10)), stride: 5)
```

You can get a (marginally) better render out of having more points in your path, but an even better way to do it would be to make a path out of curves instead of lines. For extra credit, try extending the `NSBezierPath(linesBetween:)` initializer above to add curves by keeping every `n`th point as part of the path while using a couple of the intermediary points as control handles. (It's no general purpose auto trace algorithm, but might be good enough for cases like this.)

Comment: Wow. JUST WOW!!! This is first class documentation. On behalf of all frustrated design oriented, tactile illustrators accustomed to drawing with a pen, mouse or tablet, I thank you!

Comment: The thing with the path is, that it is created by the user of my app, so I do not know in advance how many and which point the path will contain. THANK YOU for this great answer!! :)

Comment: To gather the data for this example, we asked a user to draw a circle in the air. Obviously, the outcome not a perfect circle. Ideally, we would recognise it as a circle and then change the data to draw a perfect circle instead. But that's a different problem...

Comment: Yeah, you definitely can't count on being able to feed user sketches into `SCNShape`. And as you note, recognizing something "circle-ish" as an actual circle is an entirely separate problem... though there's decades of published research you can leverage for it.

Comment: This is an amazing answer.

Answer (score 2):

In no way does this compare to Rikster's answer, but there is another way to prevent this kind of problem. It's a commercial way, and there's probably freeware apps that do similar, but this is one I'm used to using, that does this quite well.

What is 'this' that I'm talking about?

The conversion of drawings to code, by an app called PaintCode. This will allow you to see your paths and be sure they have none of the conflicts that Rickster pointed out are your issue.

Check it out here: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Other options are listed in answers here: [How to import/parse  SVG into UIBezierpaths, NSBezierpaths, CGPaths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481876/how-to-import-parse-svg-into-uibezierpaths-nsbezierpaths-cgpaths)